# Jmeter - How to write custom message when connection could not be established using JDBC

Tags: jmeter

I am using VPN in order to establish my jdbc connection.
Many times I forgot to activate my vpn, and the variable that I expect from JDBC is not provided or I
got something like

```
2022-01-26 10:45:44,730 ERROR o.a.j.f.Jexl3Function: An error occurred while evaluating the expression "${db_#} == 0"

org.apache.commons.jexl3.JexlException$Tokenization: @1:7 tokenization error in '#'
    at org.apache.commons.jexl3.JexlEngine.createScript(JexlEngine.java:316) ~[commons-jexl3-3.1.jar:3.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.functions.Jexl3Function.execute(Jexl3Function.java:96) [ApacheJMeter_functions.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable.execute(CompoundVariable.java:135) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable.execute(CompoundVariable.java:110) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.FunctionProperty.getStringValue(FunctionProperty.java:100) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.testelement.AbstractTestElement.getPropertyAsString(AbstractTestElement.java:280) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.IfController.getCondition(IfController.java:170) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.IfController.next(IfController.java:230) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.nextIsAController(GenericController.java:221) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:174) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.ForeachController.next(ForeachController.java:209) [ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.3]
```

Is there any way to make a custom message, when the value is not provided from JDBC?

Answer (score 0):

A custom message where? If [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) is a viable option you could add a [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the JDBC request sampler and use the code like:

```
if (vars.get('db_#') == null) {
    log.warn('Variable db_# is not defined')
}
```

[image]

See [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) to learn what do these `log` and `vars` shorthands stand for